# Methods for high current DC motor emergency cutoff

Tags: dc-motor, safety, h-bridge, flyback, high-current

I need to add a secondary means of cutting off power to a motor for safety reasons if a state change is detected on a 3.3V logic level signal while it is operating. The requirement I have is that **it must be external to the existing system, fitting inline with the motor connector.**

Currently, the brushed DC motor is driven bidirectionally with 12V (SLA battery, so realistically 11.5-13.5V) PWM using an H-Bridge onboard like the image below. This protection cutoff would essentially need to fit between the bridge and the motor, in the area of the red box

Right now I've considered a few solutions, but have the following concerns:

- High Motor Current: Nominally about 5A, but if stalled could reach ~50A
  for a short period before FW detects the condition or our 20A slow
  fuse goes. I'm seeking parts rated to ~75A to provide some margin.
- Bidirectional Drive: Whereas a high-side PFET may have been an easy
  solution if driven in one direction, bidirectional drive with the
  H-bridge makes a discrete solutions with FETs more complicated.
- Flyback voltage: Since it is driven bidirectionally with the
  H-bridge, a simple flyback diode can't be placed across the
  terminals. I'm unsure with how to mitigate flyback voltage from this cutoff without interfering with normal bidirectional operation. I'm also concerned that flyback will damage my cutoff circuitry, particularly if I use a semiconductor device

Here are some solutions I'm considering so far:

- MOSFET Discrete "E-Fuse"
- Integrated E-Fuse, or Load switch, possibly with external FET(s)
- Relays, Electromechanical or solid state
- Some sort of SPDT switch, which could be used to simultaneously cutoff power and short the battery terminals to circulate flyback current (though I haven't found any sort of high power component for this...)

Any feedback on my considered solutions or suggestions would be great. My main difficulty is that finding parts that work bidirectionally and handle adequate current has not been easy, so I'm wondering if I'm looking at the wrong types of solutions.

[image: H-Bridge]

Comment: If you peruse various websites which cater to DIY electric vehicles, you will find they sell solenoids which could be used for this purpose. I would not use a semiconductor device.

Comment: Your question is confusing: 1.) what an emergency cutoff has to do with your description? 2.) What's means bidirectionally driven? ... A motor shall be protected with appropriate fuse I^2 t rating., but you can also implement an electronic overcurrent detection., but all this has nothing to do with emergency stop.

Comment: Also: the protection shall not be as depicted in red box, rather on H-bridge supply.

Comment: Are you sensing current with a 1 to 5 mohm shunt?  then you can regulated PWM to prevent rotor or driver meltdown.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes we are, but we are looking for a redundant safety solution external to the existing PCB, without a respin. I can design a new PCB for this solution, but I can't modify the existing driving circuitry.

Comment: Consider a low side NFET in the ground connection to the bridge. (I'm assuming you need an independent cutoff rather than messing with both low side gate drivers)

Comment: @user_1818839 That, or a high side PFET would have been my choice if I could modify the existing boards. Unfortunately that is not an option in this case, as it must be placed between the PCB and the motor terminals.

Comment: Then you may be looking at a contactor of some sort, or possibly a solid state relay.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  Please see the first couple paragraphs again, that covers the existing system and constraints. The emergency power cutoff IS the only goal here, all the other details are relevant to the existing design and are constraints I must work within. Based on the design requirements, the solution MUST sit in the outlined box (All I have access to are the 2 motor terminals, GND, and the sensor logic signal which must trigger cutoff). And by bidirectionally, I mean the H Bridge drives current in both directions across the motor.

Comment: Safety emergency stop is done with a relay (controlled by emergency stop switch- red mushroom) that cuts the power off to the bridge, not related to the fuses or whatever. For fusing (overcurent protection), it has to be placed to the H-bridge supply and not on the motor terminals, do you understand?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Appreciate the insight, but that sounds like a very specific implementation of an "emergency stop", though similar to our intention. I realize that in some contexts, these terms may have very rigid definitions, but not for this application. In our case, we do not have access to the bridge supply without a board re-spin, which is currently not an option. I mentioned the fusing/etc. to give an idea of the absolute maximum current that a device inline with the motor may have to withstand during operation.

Comment: There is no doubt about what "emergency stop" should mean. It is divided in four main categories and their implementation with respect to the human injuries the device can provoke. So don't mix apples and potatoes.  As for your question, you can't disconnect the motor from the H-bridge, else you will burn the bridge. So, the only way is to disconnect the bridge from power, in the same manner as emergency stop would do - switch off the device (power section).

Comment: Does it preclude operator intervention?  With a 600 mV shunt at 40 amps a transistor could reset a latching relay.

Comment: "Emergency" implies safety of personnel is involved. This means a certain amount of system design is needed. Simply disconnecting a DC motor will not necessarily stop the motor, although it will cause the motor torque to drop to zero. As an example, a hoist or winch motor, when disconnected, might allow a load to drop dangerously fast. Anyway, I think you need a relay or solenoid. But Marko is right, if you disconnect the motor, the H-bridge may be destroyed (especially if the load current is 50 Amps at time of disconnect).

Comment: Maybe you can add a brake. When the logic signal is asserted, a powerful brake locks the rotor of the motor. A slow blow fuse could be added to make sure the locked rotor current does not go on indefinitely. This would need to be tested, of course.

Comment: @mkeith What affect would cause burnout of the H-bridge if current to the motor is disconnected? I'm aware that flyback voltage will be created by the motor inductance, but the MOSFETs will be protected by their body diodes. The present H-bridge FETs are well de-rated at 130A/55V ratings, and their body diodes can carry the full current continuously, much more under surge conditions. Otherwise, the "motor" load will now look like a high impedance and draw very little current under static conditions. Am I leaving something out here?

Comment: @mkeith Regarding the emergency/safety aspect, I have confirmed with our mechanical design that dropping motor torque to 0 will pause movement of the system we are adding the protection mechanism to.  Due to other factors in the design, this creates a safe state. In addition, this is a redundant safety, we have other mechanical and firmware protections to prevent the situation from occurring unless those systems fail.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Operator intervention is absolutely acceptable. This protection should NOT be tripped during operation unless some other critical fault has occurred, which in itself should be serviced. I'll look into the latching relay recommended and see if it fits the situation, thank you.

Comment: I was thinking of the voltage spike caused by suddenly stopping current to the motor. But you are right. The body diodes will clamp the voltage, and since the power source is a battery, there is no need to worry about over-voltage either (the energy from the spike will simply charge the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 solutions :

1. If you are allowed to, simply cut the power supply of the H bridge : it is still independent from your main system, and it's far easier (a mosfet or a relay is enough, and you don't have to worry about voltage spikes or energy dissipation, as this should already be taken care of by the H bridge itself). EDIT : I have just seen the comment you added that you don't have access to anything except ground, the signal and the 2 wires going to the motor. If it's really so, then it won't work. But if for example you have access to the battery, then you can cut the current right at the output of the battery
2. If you are not allowed solution 1), then you might consider using a relay. To avoid voltage spikes, you might put 2 zener diodes (with nominal voltage above the normal voltage of the supply) in serie (one in each direction) between the 2 sides of the motor: they will clamp the over-voltage. You can find zener diodes with very high current ratings. Just be carefull about power : if you have a lot of inertia, then the zener diodes are likely to overheat. If that's the case, you might use a relay with 2 position, and when you disconnect the motor from the H-bridge, you connect a power resistor between the 2 sides of the motor : the zener diodes will then only conduct for the short time until the relay finished to change position
3. How unlikely is that emergency stopping. If it is only theoretical, then a simple relay on one of the motors wire is enough : you will get voltage spikes, it's not unlikely that you brake something, but the motor is no longer powered. If you expect the likelyhood of using this emergency higher than 1%, then forget about this solution

Comment: Not sure why TVS style back to back Zeners didn't occur to me, I think that will pretty cleanly solve the flyback voltage issue if I can find a part that can withstand the current. Luckily this is just a safety backup, so it shouldn't have to regularly endure the shutoff condition. I'll have to look into using relays a bit more to determine if I can properly drive them with the signals I have available.

Answer (score 1):

If your 3.3 V line is able to provide at least about 2 mA of current, do the following:

Run the line through a photovoltaic isolator providing ~9V isolated voltage. Get two fat NMOSFETs back to back, sources tied together. Gates tied together. Turn them on with 9 V from the isolator.

When the 3V signal goes low, the MOSFETs switch off slowly and current cannot pass through the motor.

Advantage over a relay is that it is easier to drive and that the transistors turn off slowly.
Depending on the size of the motor, due to the slow turn off, you won't need TVS in parallel. For a large motor you will though.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a resistor (small value less than an ohm) to monitor the current of the bridge (between ground and the bridge). You will have to monitor this with an ADC or have a dedicated circuit to stop the drive to the H-bridge transistors in case of a high current.

Comment: I dont think adding a very small resistor provides any protection.

Comment: The resistor is not the protection. It is a means to measure the current thru the bridge and act if a high current is detected.

Comment: @Rodo I appreciate the response, but please see my reply to Tony Stewart in the comments of my original post. We do have an integrated bridge driver that monitors current sense resistors, but we are looking for an external, redundant protection.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you connect a fuse in series with the motor? In order for the fuse to open the circuit at 3.3V divide that by the resistance of the motor Rm and buy a fuse of the same rating with the current through the motor at 3.3V.

Comment: The question asks about cutting off a high-current motor from an external stimulus, not cutting off a motor due to overcurrent.

Comment: Not to mention that it is definitely NOT how a fuse is selected

Comment: I missed that issue as well - this is dangerous advice and not how a fuse is selected. Please amend.